# Identify architecture of COM object when using win32com in Python

Tags: python, autoit, win32com

I'm using AutoItX in Python as a COM object.

How do I know if the AutoIt that was installed on the machine is 32 or 64 bits using this object?

```
import win32com.client
autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
```

Comment: I admit that I have no experience with autoitx or python COM stuff, but I would bet money that if you are using the win32com.client in python then it would only be able to use the 32bit autoitx control.

Comment: What I would do is: install only 32bit autoit, try that code and see if it works, then uninstall autoit 32bit and install autoit 64bit and try that code again and see if it works. Use a try,except block and see if you get any exception for the .Dispatch() part. I would bet that you would get an exception if only the 64bit autoit is installed.

Comment: 1. win32com.client works on both 32 and 64 bit COM objects, and in Python64 as well
2. I would like to run a script on a client's machine and discover in code which architecture is installed.

Comment: The version of AutoIt has to match the version of Python (32/64). The exception is raised if the user did not install AutoIt, or installed the wrong version. Problem is that if the script raises an exception we don't know if it's because AutoIt was not installed or installed the wrong version.